# Check if user.config is not exist

Tags: c#, application-settings

My application use application settings to store user's settings, the settings file name is user.config which stored in folder Application Data. In the first run of application, the file does not exist. I want to check if the user runs my application in the first time by the way I based on this file's existence. How to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ways.. one will be to check if some key value is empty:

```
string sValue = ReadSetting("myKey");
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sValue))
{
   //file doesn't exist, handle...
}
```

And another way simple check using `System.IO.File`:

```
if (!File.Exists("user.config"))
{
   //file doesn't exist, handle...
}
```

Edit: to play safe with `File.Exists` have such code to generate the file full path:

```
string strConfigPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName), "user.config");
if (!File.Exists(strConfigPath))
   ...
```

This code is using `System.Diagnostics` namespace and will "map" the config file to the same folder as the active process.

Comment: The second one doesn't look very reliable to me. Are you sure that it works regardless of what the working directory is?

Comment: I the user config really in the application directory? That doesn't make much sense, since often the application doesn't even have write-access there.

Comment: @Code all the programs I've written that use "external" settings has their configuration file in the same folder.. been like this since Delphi 10 years ago and still the same with C# applications. Of course if that's not the case *Lu Lu* will have to explain how to "map" the file, if relevant at all. :)

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar once with a small flag set to 0 by default and setting it to 1 the first time the application runs. All following times the flag will have value 1 so you will know it's not the first time anymore.